# Perl: using Class::Struct vs explicit Perl object reference

Tags: perl

I'm very new to Perl so please bear with me... I recently saw a script that uses `Class::Struct` as such:

**[Class::Struct](http://perldoc.perl.org/Class/Struct.html)**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

package Animal;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Class::Struct;

struct Animal => {
  species => '$'
};

sub species {
  print "In species";
}

package main;

my $x;
$x = Animal->new;
```

**Output:** In species

My understanding is that this essentially a shortcut for following:

**[Perl object reference](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html)**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

package Animal;

use strict;
use warnings;

sub new {
  my $class = shift;
  my $self = {};
  bless $self, $class;
  return $self;
}

sub species {
  print "In species";
}

package main;

my $x;
$x = Animal->new;
```

**Output:**

I didn't expect the `Class::Struct` example to output: **In species**. This seems to indicate that all *sub/methods* listed in the struct are run when running `Animal->new` but I'm not sure why this is the case. I expected `Class::Struct` to just create accessor methods and provide me with a `new` method for getting an object reference.

So my questions are:

- Is my understanding essentially correct?
- Why is `Class::Struct` running all the methods on initialisation?
- Am I missing anything?

**Update**
Previous to Perl 5.18.0 this was not the default behaviour as illustrated here: https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=29230

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taken from [Class::Struct's documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Class::Struct):

> Each element in the struct data has an accessor method, which is used to assign to the element and to fetch its value. The default accessor can be overridden by declaring a sub of the same name in the package. (See Example 2.)

And later on (emphasis added):

> Scalar ('$' or '*$')
>
> The element is a scalar, and by default is **initialized to undef** (but see "Initializing with new").
>
> The accessor's argument, if any, is assigned to the element.

The `new` call tries to set the `species` property to undef by calling the accessor sub `species` defined in your package.

As a Dumper call in the accessor routine shows:

```
sub species {
  print "In species\n";
  use Data::Dumper;
  print Dumper(\@_);
}
```

Outputs:

```
In species
$VAR1 = [
      bless( {}, 'Animal' ),
      undef
    ];
```

Comment: Aha! I missed that later part of the documentation! Thanks @chris-s

Answer (score 4):

If you have an attribute called `species`, [`Class:Struct`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Class::Struct) sets up an accessor called `species` for that, and it also calls that accessor to initialize it with `undef` during object construction:

> Each element in the struct data has an accessor method, which is used to assign to the element and to fetch its value. The default accessor can be overridden by declaring a sub of the same name in the package. (See Example 2.)
>
> ...
>
> Scalar (`'$'` or `'*$'`)
>
> The element is a scalar, and by default is initialized to `undef`

You confuse that process by defining a sub called `species` that *is not an accessor*. You will never be able to set the value of the `species` field, and, every time you try to read the value of `species`, you'll get `1` alongside "in species" being printed, so, it will just serve to confuse matters.

In fact, running your example already tells you what's going on:

> `function 'species' already defined, overrides struct accessor method at ./struct.pl line 10.`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

package Animal;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Class::Struct;

struct Animal => {
  species => '$'
};

package main;

my $x;
$x = Animal->new;

$x->species('specious');

print $x->species, "\n";
```

So, to answer your question:

> - Why is `Class::Struct` running all the methods on initialisation?

It is not running *all* methods. It is using the accessors to initialize the object as good encapsulation requires.

Comment: Despite the warning, the documentation includes an [example](https://metacpan.org/pod/Class::Struct#Example-2) of how to explicitly override the default accessor like this.

Comment: Ah, excellent point. I read your "don't do that" as "don't define subs with the same name as accessors."

Comment: If one knows what one is doing, one can, of course, silence the warning locally by using `no warnings` in the applicable scope. Maybe this should be included in the docs. Dunno. Never used the module.

Comment: @sinan-Ünür Thanks, I'm aware I didn't override it with an accessor, I was just keeping it simple to show that the method was being called on object creation.

Comment: No objection, just clarifying my intent. My confusion stemmed from why running `Animal->new` was calling `Animal->species` which thanks to yours and @ThisSuitIsBlackNot answers I now understand.